# Clarification on Using Minimal Prefix Sum for Subarray Sum Problems

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of the "minimal prefix sum" in competitive programming, particularly for problems involving finding the maximum or minimum sum of subarrays. While I understand the concept of prefix sums, the leap to using a minimal prefix sum for optimization escapes me.

**Main Confusion:**

How does the minimal prefix sum contribute to finding optimal subarray sums efficiently?

Could someone break down the application of this technique with a straightforward example?

Comment: Where did you meet the concept of "minimal prefix sum"? Kadane's algorithm of finding max-sum subarray is based on resetting current sum in key moments.

Comment: "minimal prefix sum" as an alternative to Kadane's algorithm for maximum subarray sums. Unlike Kadane, which resets the sum when negative, this approach uses prefix sums and tracks their minimums to find the max difference, revealing the optimal subarray sum. It's a fresh, efficient perspective, leveraging cumulative sums for optimization in competitive programming.

Comment: Seems it is worth to add a link to some good description

Answer (score 2):

When you have constructed a prefix sum array from an array, you can obtain the sum of elements in a subarray between the indexes [l, r] in O(1) time by calculating `psa[r] - psa[l - 1]`.

Now, let us consider the maximum sum of a subarray ending at an index `i`. Let the starting point of this subarray be `j` (where j <= i). The sum of this subarray is given by `psa[i] - psa[j - 1]`. `i` is fixed, so we treat `psa[i]` as a constant and can only move `j`. Since we are subtracting `psa[j - 1]`, we want to minimize the amount that is subtracted to maximize the result. As such, we are looking for the minimum `psa[j - 1]` for all 1 <= j <= i (assuming 1-indexing), i.e. the minimum prefix sum before the current index.

To obtain the maximum subarray sum in the whole array, we repeat the above procedure for every index in the array for O(n) time and space complexity.

Comment: Good explanation! The question needs some examples/scenarios for a better answer.